# How to assign the value of AutoCompleteTextView from Dropdown selected value to another String

Tags: android

Friend's 
      I need help on setting the data content showing from DropDownlist of auto complete text box to another string,when i click the particular content from dropdown list.
Help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set onitemclicklistener for my AutoCompleteTextView and in it I manually do setText for the AutoCompleteTextView:

```
    editNumber = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
    NumberAdapter adapter = new NumberAdapter(
            this, 
            ContactInfo.getContacts(this.getContentResolver()));
    editNumber.setAdapter(adapter);

    editNumber.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ....

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    ContactInfo ci = (ContactInfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    editNumber.setText(ci.Number);
}
```